# Only vertical scrollbars with div over a vertical edge

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a list in HTML with only a vertical scrollbar. I understand how to do this but the part where I get stuck is positioning a div inside the overflow'd element over the edges of the overflow'd element.

See code below:

```
#wrapper {margin: 50px; width: 500px; height: 500px;}
#scrollable {width: 200px; height: 500px; overflow-y: visible; overflow-x: hidden;}
.item {clear: left; width: 200px; height: 40px;}

<body>
  <div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='scrollable'>
      <div class='item'></div>
      <div class='item'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want the .item elements to go 5 or 10 pixels over the left edge of #scrollable.

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: This cannot be done this way, that's just how overflow works, everything that moves out side of the visible area of the container gets hidden. Why do you want to offset the elements 5 to 10 pixels to the left of its parent container? I'm just not sure what fix ore hack could be done with out more info about why you are trying this.

Comment: Im listing some items in a list and when one of those items is selected it will go five or ten pixels over the left edge to represent that it is the active item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as others have said, you cannot show elements out of the bounds of an elements that has an  overflow that is not "visible."

However, assuming you're simply trying to achieve an effect, you can do so easily. One way would be, if your `#scrollable` element must be 200px, then make each `.item` 190px in width, and offset by 10px to the left. Otherwise, if you're `.items` must be 200px in width, then make your `#scrollable` element 210px to compensate. Then, on selection, offset left by 0.

I've made a JSFiddle with it. Take a look *(the JS in it is unnecessary, but just mimics a selection)*
http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/tpfLZ/

Answer (score 0):

In #wrapper, add: overflow: visible;
In #scrollable, add: margin-left: -10px; (you may need to set width: 210px to compensate)

Test to make sure this does what you're looking for. (Note that this will make items > 200px get cut off to the right)

Comment: That just pushes the .item element left 10 pixels under the #scrollable element.

Comment: Did you add overflow:visible to #wrapper? When I copy and paste the code you gave me, it works fine (Safari 5).

Comment: Is wrapper scrolling? What I want ideally is for no scrolling on wrapper either.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. Really I can't see a solution to what you're trying to do without changing the whole design of your code. The best thing is to probably move the whole #wrapper or #scrollable left 10 pixels.